# How does the Tetsujin 28 movie fit into the series?

Tags: tetsujin-28

I'm referring specifically to the 2004 **Tetsujin 28** spin-off and the accompanying 2007 movie **Tetsujin 28: Morning Moon of Mid-day**. You'd think that the movie must be early in the TV series because of the characters:

> Ryuusaku Murasame is still alive in the movie

but at the end of the movie

> Chief Chloroform was killed, when he was seen in the TV series well after Ryuusaku was killed

Also the whole thing with Shotaro's "brother" doesn't even come up at all in the TV series.

Are the movie and TV series different continuities (though the description has them both adapted from the same Manga by Yokoyama Mitsuteru)? Or do they somehow fit together?